# Layout problem in Android Studio, but not in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

I've just moved from Eclipse to Android Studio, and I get a problem with the following xml layout. Note that it's flawless in Eclipse.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/tabview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2" >
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
   <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:clickable="true" >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnKnowledge"
                android:background="@drawable/right_buttom_btn_line"
                android:text="@string/learn"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/h_know"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnDictionaryManager"
                android:background="@drawable/right_buttom_btn_line"
                android:text="@string/csdl_"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dic_db2" 
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is correctly shown in Eclipse as expected, but in Android Studio the images in the middle are missing.
[image]
[image]

**What is the problem? How can it be solved?**
Help appreciated.

Comment: try clean build and run and then not able to see try invalidate and restart. in my studio this layout file work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageViews` are probably hidden by the buttons. Add a small elevation to your `ImageViews` - something like `2dp`. You are probably seeing a difference in API levels between your Eclipse setup and Android Studio (a guess.)